# how to use nested class in another class in java?

Tags: java, inner-classes

I have some situation that I want to use inner class of another class in another class.
like...

```
public class ListData {
    public  static class MyData {

        public String textSongName, textArtistName, textDuration, textDownloadPath,
                textSongSize, textAlbumName, textUrl;
        public boolean enable;

        public MyData(String songName, String artistName, String duration,
                String downloadPath, String songSize, String albumName,
                String url, boolean e) {
            textSongName = songName;
            textArtistName = artistName;
            textDuration = duration;
            textDownloadPath = downloadPath;
            textSongSize = songSize;
            textAlbumName = albumName;
            textUrl = url;
            enable = e;
        }
    }

}
```

now I want to use Mydata class in another.

how can I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: You can, but don't you think you should make it top-level. (Btw: terminology post-1.1 is nested class for a "static inner class". Inner class for non-static nested classes.)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
ListData.MyData myData = new ListData.MyData();
```

Comment: So nested classes are as if they exist inside the scope of outer class?

Comment: No. Here, MyData is a static inner class. Id doesn't depend on the parent class and doesn't have access to the internals of bounded class. I fixed a mistake, caused by wrong formatting.

Comment: (Sorry for previous comment, missed the static in the inner class declaration.) Non-static inner classes are within the bounds of their outer class, in fact you can't have an instance of the inner without one of the outer. Static inner classes are encapsulated within their enclosing class but contain no reference to it, they essentially behave like separate classes otherwise.

Answer (score 21):

Static Nested Classes

```
OuterClass.StaticNestedClass nestedObject = new OuterClass.StaticNestedClass();
```

Inner Classes

```
OuterClass.InnerClass innerObject = outerObject.new InnerClass();
```

[More about Nested Classes](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html)

Comment: I know this has been sitting here a long time but...
Shouldn't the example for Inner Classes also include a line to instantiate the OuterClass object? Something like:

OuterClass outerObject = new OuterClass();

I know this is implied, but it would be better for people who don't completely understand the topic.

Answer (score 2):

If you can create inner class object from other class that is out of scope from your enclosing class   than you should use its fully qualified name....
Here , your outer class is ListData and your Inner class is Mydata
and we call Mydata from another class eg. YourData..
than we can use below statement..

Syntax :
         outerclass.innerclass = new outerclass.innerclass();

=>      **ListData.MyData objectname = new ListData.MyData();**

**NOTE : this can use only when innner class is static..**